# rke etcd snapshot have so many errors

Tags: kubernetes, etcd, rke

i have to backup my kubernetes cluster.
i choose Etcd backup with rancher rke but after restoring the backup i have too many differente errors on pods like Calico, Nginx-ingress-controller, kube-dns and ... .

is Etcd backup reliable?
what is the best backup tools for kubernetes?

i tried step by step restore from:
https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/backups/restorations/ha-restoration/#4-restore-database

Comment: Please, upvote/accept the answer to let know community about usefulness, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One of the most popular is [Valero](https://velero.io/docs/v1.1.0/), which gives you tools to back up and restore your Kubernetes cluster resources and persistent volumes. You can run Velero with a cloud provider or on-premises. It is well documented. You can check [installation overview](https://velero.io/docs/v1.1.0/install-overview/) to see details.

You can also check [tutorial](https://blog.kubernauts.io/backup-and-restore-of-kubernetes-applications-using-heptios-velero-with-restic-and-rook-ceph-as-2e8df15b1487) how to srart with Valero. If you have more question feel free to ask.